Morphisms in Monoids
As I am trying to learn Category Theory (CT) which is very relevant to my line of research, I am coming across the idea that, in CT, we don't have an "internal view" of say a group as made up of elements but an "external" view of a collection of groups (called objects) with morphisms defined between them. This precisely aligns with the idea of group homomoprhisms, which is fine.
However, in the case of monoid, I am given to understand that a monoid is a single object and the morphisms are its elements. Should the set of monoids be a category and morphisms defined between them than considering a monoid as a single object and morphisms as its elements? If that is the case, is it the same with the groups that its elements are actually morphisms?

I'm not sure I get what you're asking, but there's two ways you can view groups/monoids: Classically, as sets of elements together with certain operations (these, together with the homomorphisms, together form a category of groups/monoids), or categorially as one-object categories with the endomorphisms of that object being given by the group/monoid. A homomorphism of groups/monoids is then simply a functor.

I think you might be over-interpreting the phrase "a monoid is a one-object (locally small) category". When a category theorist says "is", sometimes this just means "can be thought of as" or "is naturally isomorphic to". In this case, a monoid is also "a set equipped with an associative operation and an identity element", and you can indeed just as well talk about "the category of monoids". Sometimes there is just more than one way that category theory can be applied to a certain concept!

@BenSteffan this makes sense. That is, treating homomorphism as a functor between two objects. In this case, I guess the group/monoid elements are endomorphisms.

@IzaakvanDongen, I think the key is what you said as a last sentence. I think here I am talking about category with a single object vs category with multiple objects.

@IzaakvanDongen, "I think here I am talking about category with a single object vs category with multiple objects" should read as "I think here I am talking about category as a single object vs category with multiple objects with mappings between them."

I think the problem here arises from two different connections between the concepts of monoid and category. (1) There is a category of all monoids (analogous to the category of groups you described). Its objects are all of the  monoids, and its morphisms are homomorphisms of monoids (i.e., functions that preserve the multiplication operation and the identity element). (2) Every single monoid $M$ can be viewed as a category with just one object; the morphisms are the elements of $M$, and composition is the multiplication operation of $M$.

@AndreasBlass you are right on spot!
